# Performing operations on group by based on column value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a grouped pandas dataframe

```
x   y   id  date        qty
6   3   932 2017-05-14  212  
6   3   932 2017-05-15  212  
6   3   932 2017-05-18  212  
6   3   933 2016-10-03  518  
6   3   933 2016-10-09  16  
6   3   933 2016-10-15  28
```

I want to know how to get the number of days between each order for a particular id. The first date should be the 0th day and the consecutive column values the number of days after the first order. Something like this

```
x   y  id  date  qty
6   3  932  0   212  
6   3  932  1   212  
6   3  932  3   212  
6   3  933  0   518  
6   3  933  6   16  
6   3  933  6   28
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `id` and get [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), repalce `NaT` with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and last  get [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
print (df)

   x  y   id        date  qty
0  6  3  932  2017-05-14  212
1  6  3  932  2017-05-15  212
2  6  3  932  2017-05-18  212
3  6  3  933  2016-10-03  518
4  6  3  933  2016-10-09   16
5  6  3  933  2016-10-15   28

#if necessary convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = df.groupby(['id'])['date'].diff().fillna(0).dt.days
print (df)

   x  y   id  date  qty
0  6  3  932     0  212
1  6  3  932     1  212
2  6  3  932     3  212
3  6  3  933     0  518
4  6  3  933     6   16
5  6  3  933     6   28
```

And [Zero's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46293347/2901002) is very similar, only output is `float` and not `int`, because of ordering of functions.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for ! Thank you. Is the date column's dtype int ?

Comment: Sure, exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `diff()` on `date` of `id` groups, then using accessor to get `dt.days` days, fill `NaN`s with `0`

```
In [772]: df.groupby('id')['date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0)
Out[772]:
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    3.0
3    0.0
4    6.0
5    6.0
Name: date, dtype: float64

In [773]: df['date'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0)

In [774]: df
Out[774]:
   x  y   id  date  qty
0  6  3  932   0.0  212
1  6  3  932   1.0  212
2  6  3  932   3.0  212
3  6  3  933   0.0  518
4  6  3  933   6.0   16
5  6  3  933   6.0   28
```

---

Details

Original `df`

```
In [776]: df
Out[776]:
   x  y   id        date  qty
0  6  3  932  2017-05-14  212
1  6  3  932  2017-05-15  212
2  6  3  932  2017-05-18  212
3  6  3  933  2016-10-03  518
4  6  3  933  2016-10-09   16
5  6  3  933  2016-10-15   28

In [778]: df.dtypes
Out[778]:
x                int64
y                int64
id               int64
date    datetime64[ns]
qty              int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: and last astype(int)